# which linux can you use bitwig daw

Tags: daw

which linux can you use bitwig

Comment: Why don't risk a look at their [homepage](https://www.bitwig.com/download/)?

Comment: Hi. How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Their website says Ubuntu 18.04 or later. That’s probably saved you about 45 seconds research ;) !